# Obtener coordenada única a partir de grupo de coordenadas google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-v3

Buenas tardes, tengo las siguientes coordenadas que las obtuve de un kml, dichas coordenadas dibujan una linea alrededor de un área. Las coordenadas son las siguientes:

-90.833910,13.994037 -90.833918,13.994095 -90.833924,13.994152 -90.833930,13.994207 -90.833936,13.994263 -90.833943,13.994322 -90.833951,13.994382 -90.833959,13.994440 -90.833965,13.994494 -90.833971,13.994548 -90.833978,13.994608 -90.833984,13.994671 -90.833993,13.994741 -90.834001,13.994811 -90.834010,13.994877 -90.834019,13.994940 -90.834028,13.995003 -90.834036,13.995060 -90.834044,13.995110 -90.834052,13.995162 -90.834061,13.995222 -90.834067,13.995281 -90.834074,13.995336 -90.834080,13.995390 -90.834086,13.995442 -90.834092,13.995495 -90.834100,13.995553 -90.834105,13.995610 -90.834110,13.995665 -90.834116,13.995718 -90.834122,13.995769 -90.834127,13.995820 -90.834134,13.995871 -90.834141,13.995924 -90.834146,13.995974 -90.834149,13.996008 -90.834192,13.996161 -90.834732,13.996091 -90.835519,13.995989 -90.836038,13.995931 -90.836696,13.995846 -90.836677,13.995819 -90.836660,13.995674 -90.836610,13.995123 -90.836480,13.994146 -90.836461,13.994126 -90.836370,13.994036 -90.836287,13.994044 -90.836194,13.994035 -90.836012,13.993789 -90.836003,13.993753 -90.835995,13.993581 -90.836245,13.993529 -90.836375,13.993521 -90.836386,13.993516 -90.836394,13.993512 -90.836394,13.993503 -90.836395,13.993404 -90.836309,13.992635 -90.836266,13.992318 -90.836207,13.991926 -90.836192,13.991927 -90.836170,13.991932 -90.836125,13.991938 -90.836074,13.991943 -90.836010,13.991951 -90.835936,13.991961 -90.835862,13.991968 -90.835791,13.991976 -90.835722,13.991980 -90.835658,13.991985 -90.835597,13.991994 -90.835533,13.992003 -90.835471,13.992011 -90.835408,13.992018 -90.835346,13.992025 -90.835285,13.992033 -90.835228,13.992040 -90.835173,13.992045 -90.835118,13.992051 -90.835062,13.992057 -90.835002,13.992063 -90.834936,13.992071 -90.834868,13.992078 -90.834800,13.992086 -90.834733,13.992094 -90.834663,13.992102 -90.834588,13.992111 -90.834523,13.992120 -90.834474,13.992123 -90.834421,13.992129 -90.834361,13.992133 -90.834298,13.992140 -90.834229,13.992149 -90.834160,13.992161 -90.834092,13.992171 -90.834022,13.992180 -90.833954,13.992185 -90.833889,13.992191 -90.833824,13.992198 -90.833761,13.992205 -90.833709,13.992212 -90.833680,13.992216 -90.833683,13.992242 -90.833693,13.992300 -90.833704,13.992370 -90.833712,13.992445 -90.833720,13.992518 -90.833727,13.992591 -90.833736,13.992661 -90.833745,13.992730 -90.833755,13.992795 -90.833764,13.992855 -90.833772,13.992913 -90.833779,13.992971 -90.833786,13.993033 -90.833792,13.993092 -90.833799,13.993149 -90.833807,13.993202 -90.833815,13.993251 -90.833823,13.993302 -90.833830,13.993358 -90.833837,13.993410 -90.833843,13.993462 -90.833849,13.993518 -90.833857,13.993579 -90.833864,13.993641 -90.833870,13.993700 -90.833876,13.993760 -90.833881,13.993817 -90.833887,13.993871 -90.833894,13.993927 -90.833902,13.993982 -90.833910,13.994037

Con dichas coordenadas genero estos poligonos en un mapa de google maps.

[image: Imagen]

Quiero saber si es posible obtener una coordenada central de cada poligono para así poder crear un marker en ella.

Por su ayuda muchas gracias.

Comment: Pues si dibujan un cuadrado usa la formúla matemática de la geometría para distancias o según la figura la geometría analítica,te ayudará a encontrar el centro de una figura

Comment: La pregunta es demasiado general y le falta indicar lo buscado/investigado sobre el tema. Referencia [ask].

Comment: Con esas coordenadas tú dibujas los polígonos, o los dibuja un objeto google.maps.KmlLayer ? Si es lo segundo, no hay cómo pedir las características de un feature en particular